# InvalidElementStateException using PhantomJS 2.1.1/Webdriver 2.53.0 and Visual Studio/C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

The code below executes perfect in IE, FireFox, Chrome.  In PhantomJS it seems like it's not waiting in this case, for the popup(via CSS styling on a div) to display.  If I put a sleep statement before the statement where the exception occurs the problem goes away.  Why is driver.ImplicitlyWait() not working?  I shouldn't have to litter my code with sleeps and waits with Phantom should I?

I've looked at a lot of posts and none seem to be resolving my issue.  Any thoughts on what I can try?

Facts and things i've tried...
- There is only one element with id='firstname' in the entire source code.
- This element is always found regardless of browser, this is an interactable issue.
- This element is always interactable in ff, chrome, ie without WebDriverWait.
- This element is never interactable in phantom unless using WebDriverWait.
- Setting driver.Manage().Window.size to Maximum or 1920,1080 does not resolve issue.
- Attempting different selectors such as By.CssSelector("input#firstname") and By.XPath("//div[@class='modal-body']//input[@id='firstname']") resulted in the same exception.

```
// successful code
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(home_page);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnAddEmployee")).Click();

// exception here
driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstname")).SendKeys("first name");
```

// exception
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"19","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:20943"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"value\":[\"alice\"]}","url":"/value","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"value","directory":"/","path":"/value","relative":"/value","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/value","queryKey":{},"chunks":["value"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5c641300-a229-11e6-9fa8-69dbd56d6ff7/element/:wdc:1478220923048/value"}}
Result StandardOutput:
Unable to connect to the remote server
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"19","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:20943"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"value\":[\"alice\"]}","url":"/value","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"value","directory":"/","path":"/value","relative":"/value","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/value","queryKey":{},"chunks":["value"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5c641300-a229-11e6-9fa8-69dbd56d6ff7/element/:wdc:1478220923048/value"}}
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.SendKeys(String text)
   at Test.TestCases.Test() in C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\Project\TestCases.cs:line 191

// exception screenshot
[image: exception screenshot]

```
// web page source code being automated
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <title>Benefits Dashboard</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pagePuncher.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">      
  </script>
  <script src="http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
  <script src="assets/js/employee.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script>
    function GetURLParameter(r){for(var t=window.location.search.substring(1),e=t.split("&"),n=0;n<e.length;n++){var a=e[n].split("=");if(a[0]==r)return a[1]}return""}""==GetURLParameter("username")&&(window.location.href="login.html");
  </script>
</head>
<body class="modal-open">
  <div id="uselessBlueHeader"></div>
  <div class="container">
  <div id="header" class="page-header jumbotron">
    <h1>Benefits Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="data">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="employee-table" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Dependents</th>
                <th>Gross Pay
                </th><th>Benefit Cost</th>
                <th>Net Pay</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btnAddEmployee" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEmployeeModal">Add Employee</button>

  <div class="modal fade in" id="addEmployeeModal" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee &amp; His dependents</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="employees-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="dependents">Dependants:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dependents">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="addEmployee">Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you give a try using different selector to find the element.

Comment: also, can you try to maximise browser using: driver.manage().window().maximize();  I saw couple of post stating this as workaround. Do let know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Abhinav.  I've updated the post with "Facts and things i've tried".  Your suggestions unfortunately did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using an implicit wait waits till the element is visible in the dom, and doesn't check for other interactions (element state for example). i.e, in this line of code

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstname")).click()
```

The implicit wait only waits for an element with `id="firstname"` to appear and as soon as it does, the script will attempt to click on it. However, the element may not be "clickable". Behavior may vary based on several factors, which might be why you're experiencing unstable executions across browsers.

To achieve this you'll have to specifically wait till the element is clickable. You can use something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("firstname")));
```

**Note** 1. do not mix implicit and explicit wait statements in your code.
2. Proper Synchronization is an important factor if you want to have stable scripts. And synchronization is not merely about adding wait statements.
3. Littering the code with Sleep statements is not good coding practice and ideally shouldn't be used unless you're only attempting to debug the script.

**Additional Details**
I suspect the difference between other browsers and phantomjs lies in the underlying browser engines. For instance, Phantomjs uses `WebKit`and Chrome uses `Blink`.

You don't have to use the explicit wait before every action. Just after an action that causes an additional Dom element to load or results in a navigation.

Comment: Thank you for your post Sai.  Please see the updates to my post for "Facts and things i've tried".  It really bothers me that all non headless browsers don't require WebDriverWait.  They "just work" regarding interactive elements.  Why is Phantom different?  Also if I have to use WebDriverWait before using each element i'm not sure how i'd avoid littering my code with wait calls.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a few details. Will look around for more differences between browsers and drivers and keep you posted.